# code completion in pydev (eclipse) when the variable type is unknown

Tags: eclipse, pydev, assert, isinstance

for a varible with type unknown (not during runtime), for codecomplete the following statement is working

assert isinstance(variable, class)
variable. {codecomplete works}

while the following statement is not

assert isinstance(self.variable, class)
self.variable. {codecomplete not working}

how to make codecomplete work with "self.*" variables?